# How to avoid O(n^2) complexity when grouping records in XSLT?

Tags: java, performance, xslt, xerces, xalan

I'm frequently running into performance issues when I XSL transform large amounts of data into HTML. This data is usually just a couple of very large tables of roughly this form:

```
<table>
  <record>
    <group>1</group>
    <data>abc</abc>
  </record>
  <record>
    <group>1</group>
    <data>def</abc>
  </record>
  <record>
    <group>2</group>
    <data>ghi</abc>
  </record>
</table>
```

During transformation, I want to visually group the records like this

```
+--------------+
| Group 1      |
+--------------+
|   abc        |
|   def        |
+--------------+
| Group 2      |
+--------------+
|   ghi        |
+--------------+
```

A silly implementation is this one (set is from http://exslt.org. the actual implementation is a bit different, this is just an example):

```
<xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(/table/record/group)">
  <xsl:variable name="group" select="."/>

  <!-- This access needs to be made faster : -->
  <xsl:for-each select="/table/record[group = $group]">
    <!-- Do the table stuff -->
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It's easy to see that this tends to have `O(n^2)` complexity. Even worse, as there are lots of fields in every record. The data operated on can reach several dozens of MB, the number of records can go up to 5000. In the worst case, every record has its own group and 50 fields. And to make things even much worse, there is yet another level of grouping possible, making this `O(n^3)`

Now there would be quite a few options:

1. I could find a Java solution to this involving maps and nested data structures. But I want to improve my XSLT skills, so that's actually the last option.
2. I'm maybe oblivious of a nice feature in Xerces/Xalan/Exslt, that can handle grouping much better
3. I can maybe build an index of some sort for `/table/record/group`
4. You can prove to me that the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` approach is decidedly faster in this use-case than the `<xsl:for-each/>` approach.

What do you think how this `O(n^2)` complexity can be reduced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the wellknown Muenchian grouping method in XSLT 1.0 -- no need to explore sorted data and implement more complicated and slower algorithms:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kGroupByVal" match="group" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "group
      [generate-id()
      =
       generate-id(key('kGroupByVal', .)[1])
      ]">
  <group gid="{.}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kGroupByVal', .)/node()"/>
  </group>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="group/text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on your provided text** (that isn't even a well-formed XML document!!!) after correcting it to well-formedness,

**it takes 80ms for 3 `record` elements**.

**With similar text having 1000 `record` elements the transformation finishes in 136ms**.

**With 10000 `record` elements the time taken is 284ms**.

**With 100000 `record` elements the time taken is 1667ms**.

The observed complexity is clearly sublinear.

It would be very difficult (if possible at all) to find a more efficient solution than Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Don't worry about well-formedness, that's just an example to keep it simple. In this very case, @IvanDugic's solution is probably a bit faster, because indeed, the groups are already sorted in a database. So the grouping header can be created using `<xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::record[1]/group = group)"/>` But this is clearly something to keep in mind

Comment: @LukasEder: Why don't you try both solutions and take measurements?

Comment: I'm about to do that. I'll let you know

Comment: To my surprise, both solutions perform equally well in with < 2000 records. I currently can measure bigger amounts of data.

Comment: @LukasEder: Yes, and the Muenchian grouping can be coded almost mechanically and doesn't require nothing specialized.

Comment: The syntax is a bit odd, but I guess I can get used to it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

If the data is presorted by groups (as in your example), you can loop the record set and check if the group of the record is different from the preceding record group. If the group changes, you can add a group header. This will perform in O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Your current algorithm:

```
for every [group] record
  for every [data] record
    // actions
```

I assume that if you perform simple iteration through all elements and

```
 for every [record]
       take [data]
       take [group]
       add [data] to [group]
```

For group representation you can use trees or maps.

As you can see, this algorithm has complexity O(n)

Comment: I'm aware of this option, and I can easily implement this in Java. But how to do it with XSLT?

Comment: I'm not expert in xslt, but you can use <xsl:for-each select="(/table/record)"> to iterate throug all your records and <map> to create map variable

Comment: Then I'll need two transformations. One to create the map and one to transform it into HTML...

Answer (score 2):

The recommended grouping methods are xsl:for-each-group in XSLT 2.0, and Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1.0. With any half-decent processor, both of these will have (n*log(n)) performance.

Or you could simply replace `"/table/record[group = $group]"` with a call to the key() function.

If you're prepared to pay for an enterprise-class XSLT processor such as Saxon-EE, there's a good chance these optimizations will be done for you automatically so you don't have to worry about them.

Comment: I should've said that I'm using XSLT 1.0... Interesting approach with the key, though! I'll have to double-check that